# How to handle return code of ALSA API snd_pcm_writei()

Tags: linux, alsa

I am using ASLA Audio API for playing sound in my embedded linux application. Am observing at times that the `snd_pcm_writei` API returns `–EPIPE` error and when that error happens I call `snd_pcm_prepare` (that basically prepares PCM for re-use).

```
if ((err = snd_pcm_writei (playback_handle, buf, nframes)) < 0) 
{
    if ((err = snd_pcm_prepare (playback_handle)) < 0)
    return err;
}
```

I found some suggestions that instead of `snd_pcm_prepare` using `snd_pcm_recover` should be the correct approach in this instance. Before trying the fix I just wanted to know if anybody can help me out in understanding how we to set the PCM device to recover from the underrun or other errors that can happen during write.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `snd_pcm_recover()` function handles more error codes, so you should use it.
But it ends up calling `snd_pcm_prepare()` anyway (see the [source code](http://git.alsa-project.org/?p=alsa-lib.git;a=blob;f=src/pcm/pcm.c;h=bc18954b92da124bafd3a67913bd3c8900dd012f;hb=HEAD#l7864)).

There's nothing really special about `snd_pcm_prepare()`; it's just the simplest way of reinitializing the stream.

Comment: I have a doubt: is it required that we call snd_pcm_close() after every time we call snd_pcm_drain() ??

Comment: Calling `snd_pcm_close()` is *always* required. You need `snd_pcm_drain()` only to ensure that the remaining samples in the buffer are played.

Comment: In my application am calling snd_pcm_open() only once during the initialization. And whenever I see snd_pcm_writei() return -EPIPE or some error I will do snd_pcm_prepare() and snd_pcm_close(). And I feel since i dont call snd_pcm_open() again while application is running. I am facing some issue. 

After reading through web, I found that snd_pcm_drop() should also work similar to snd_pcm_close(). Please suggest me if that is correct.

Comment: You need neither `snd_pcm_close()` nor `snd_pcm_drop()` to recover from an error.

Comment: snd_pcm_drain(): For playback wait for all pending frames to be played and then stop the PCM. snd_pcm_drain() is it a blocking call ? And If I set the mode of open device as SND_PCM_NONBLOCK in snd_pcm_open() - does it be a non blocking call for snd_pcm_drain(). ?

Comment: `snd_pcm_drain()` is always blocking.

Comment: Thanks for you help I need one last suggestion. **Is there a way I can set `snd_pcm_drain()` in NON BLOCKING mode**, means the snd_pcm_drain() should return with `EAGAIN` or something similar error instead of waiting for all pending frames to be played. ?? Or is it a wise option to use `snd_pcm_drop()` instead of `snd_pcm_drain()` -- Why am asking is that, I found that in my application I was stuck waiting in `snd_pcm_drain()` API after running my application for significant amount of time (playing huge audio data). I need a way that I should return from `snd_pcm_drain()`.

Comment: If you just want to know whether there is still data being playes, use something like `snd_pcm_status()`.

Comment: Found that my problem is because of the fact that my application was hung in `snd_pcm_writei()` or `snd_pcm_drain()` API calls for certain amount of time after long playing of sounds - due to which my application exits (thinking no response from those API calls) 

I wanted to have a solution to have `snd_pcm_writei()` and `snd_pcm_drain()` work like non-blocking calls and do the job they do.

Comment: I tried opening `snd_pcm_open`( mode = `SND_PCM_NONBLOCK`) which didnt solve the problem becuase my write() call use to return immediately with EAGAIN and no sound data was fed to the driver. But when I used `SND_PCM_ASYNC` it worked fine. Is it right way to set the mode to ASYNC instead of 0 (blocking) if I ever want it to be a blocked call. ???

Comment: Don't use `SND_PCM_ASYNC`! To change the blocking mode of an opened PCM device, use `snd_pcm_nonblock()´.